# Upgrade Jenkins CI withourt losing User/Job Config

Tags: jenkins

I would like to upgrade Jenkins to the latest version without losing job/user configuration.
From looking through various posts the answer seems to be to replace the jenkins war directory.
I did this and although the new version seems to be in place the about dialogue still has the original version,
I think this is because the versionnumber is held in a config file outside of the war folder.
Is there a better method to upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

I am sharing my experience here, as this would definitely help someone. We were on **jenkins 2.138.3** and wanted to upgrade to **2.235.5** version. Now the issue we were facing is our users were getting deleted when we tried to restore the users folder from the backup of old jenkins.

**Root Cause:** In the jenkins upgrade the mechanism to store the users on the disk is changed. This is verified by seeing the users//config.xml of both old and new jenkins.

The first problem we faced starting the jenkins is below error

```
java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException: /Users/jenkins/<username>
```

The reason being, in the upgraded jenkins the username folder is changed. for e.g. if your username is admin then in new jenkins the folder would be something like **$JENKINS_HOME/users/admin_6635238516816951048/** instead of  **$JENKINS_HOME/users/admin/** and this mapping is captured separately in a file
**$JENKINS_HOME/users/users.xml** where a sample entry would look like

```
 <entry>
      <string>admin_6635238516816951048</string>
      <string>admin_6635238516816951048</string>
    </entry>
```

Here the first String is your username and second is the folder where config.xml for your user should exists.
In our old jenkins this folder structure is not available and hence we see the error

```
java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException: /Users/jenkins/<username>
```

So, what are the steps to migrate users properly so existing credentials can be used.

1. Once the new jenkins war is deployed on the new jenkins, stop the jenkins.
2. If there exists a **users.xml** file in **$JENKINS_HOME/users/users.xml**, delete it or rename it so jenkins wont look for the new folder structure
3. Restore your users folder from old jenkins to new jenkins at **$JENKINS_HOME** location. So all your users should appear in new jenkins @ **$JENKINS_HOME/users** folder
4. Start the jenkins service.
5. And you should be able to login with your old jenkins user's credentials.

The detailed explanation can be found at
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/upgrade-guide/2.138/#SECURITY-1072

Answer (score 0):

I have the best practice with replacing `jenkins.war` **file**, content of the folder should got extracted from war file during server startup (automatically).

All configuration is stored as files in jenkins home directory. 
jobs in subfolder jobs, users in users etc.

> So if you will **replace war file**, you will dont loose the configuration or content.

You can check [this](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2016/06/upgrade-jenkins-and-plugins/) for better info, looks for "Install the New Jenkins War File
"